# Reading Date from Excel file in VBA Error Message

Tags: excel, vba, function, object

I have a function that gets the date from a certain cell in an excel sheet, splits the string that was in that cell using a space as a delimiter and keeps the first object in the array to store at as the date. However, I keep getting the following error message

> "run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".

Any ideas of what might be wrong?

```vb
Public Function getDate(ws As Excel.Worksheet, row As Integer, col As Integer) As String
    Dim inspDateTime As Variant
    Dim dateArr() As String
    Dim inspDateFinal As String
    Set inspDateTime = ws.Cells(row, col)
    dateArr = Split(inspDateTime, " ")
    inspDateFinal = dateArr(0)
    getDate = inspDateFinal
End Function
```

The following code is how I call the function:

```
Private Sub UploadData_Click()
    Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim myWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim inspDate As String
    inspDate = getDate(myWorksheet, 10, 14)
    ' setting the workbook as the directory that was printed to the text box
    Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Me.FilePathTxtBox)
    ' setting the first worksheet in the array of files entered
    Set myWorksheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note, but `inspDateTime` should really be a `Range`, not a `Variant`.

Comment: Does a specific line get highlited?

Comment: How do you call the function? Likely the parameter `ws` is not set correctly

Comment: Yes, Set inspDateTime = ws.Cells(row, col) gets highlighted

Comment: is ws set, row&col identified?

Comment: I call the function with this line     inspDate = getDate(myWorksheet, 10, 14) after I initialized myWorksheet with the line Dim myWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

Comment: Can you place the code you call the function with in your original question.

Comment: Then probably the variable `myWorksheet` is not set. If you are not sure, check with the debugger. If you can't figure out, add the calling code to the post.

Comment: I added the code of how I am calling the function

Comment: As already mentioned, `myWorksheet` is not `Set` anywhere.

Comment: You declare `myWorksheet` but you don't assign anything to it. You need to tell VBA which sheet you are referring to. With the current code, `myWorksheet` points to `Nothing` and `Nothing` has no cells - thus the error.

Comment: It doesn't appear you have set  the sheets.you need something like `set ws=sheets("MySheetName")`

Comment: I do set the workbook and worksheet based on user input I just forgot to add it to my question. The workbook is set based on a user input and then I select the first worksheet in the workbook. I added the code to my original question

Comment: You are calling the function before setting the workbook and worksheet, that could be one of the issues.

Comment: Exactly, sequence should be:

    (1) Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Me.FilePathTxtBox)

    (2) Set myWorksheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    (3) inspDate = getDate(myWorksheet, 10, 14)